# Node.js | Call function from original file in imported file

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, electron, code-structure

I recently tried to organize my code by exporting functions into different files, so my main file stays clean. To do so I imported the other js file in my main file with
`const request = require('./request.js');`
In "request.js" I used `export`, so I can call the function in my main file. Is it is possible to call a function, that is defined in the main file, from the "request.js" file? Unfortunately I can't just return the information back to the main file, because I am using callbacks.

Comment: try this
$('body').on("click","your class or id", function(){ 
    // your code
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

You just need to export function from the main file and then import your main file inside `request.js`:

```
// main.js:

module.exports.someFunction = function() {
    // Some code
};

const request = require('./request.js');
request.someRequestFunction();

// request.js

var main = require('./main.js');

module.exports = {
    someRequestFunction: function() {
        main.someFunction(); // Call function from main module
    }
};
```